# read content in webbrowser input field

Tags: delphi, input, field, twebbrowser

Something I have been trying to do and still can't get done. Reading the information typed in a website input field and being able to copy that.

Is there a way I can read the ty

Comment: Can you execute Javascript against the page you render in the web browser control? is that your page or any page of the internet? if you can control the page because it belongs to you I would try with JQuery if it's possible to store the value in an hidden field for example, then I would access the dom and read the value.

Comment: no it is not my page on the internet, its any page. thats why its so difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try these articles about using [`TWebBrowser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) and delphi to read data from a web page.

- [`How to read and write form elements`](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/read_write_form_elements.htm#NamesOfAllFields)
- [TWebBrowser OleObject and Document data](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_oleobject.htm)

Comment: thx, found those before as well, but its the wrong way around. They are about placing text in boxes and not retrieving text from input fields....

Comment: @ployo replace `A := B` with `B := A`

Comment: @ployo60 I tell you what, why don't you send me the details of your project, I'll do it for you and send it back to you.

Comment: @ployo60, are you sure ('...They are about placing text in boxes and not retrieving text from input fields')?  do you read the article ?   http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/read_write_form_elements.htm#GetValueOfField

Comment: @ployo60 - this is the answer to your question. Don't expect people writing code for you. Please mark this as accepted and move on with your research, you need to learn quite a few things yet.

Comment: @David, no don't worry about it. I've done it with reading the keys that are typed. I believe that should work as well.....

Comment: @RUZZ, yeah or I am not understanding it properly..... it gives me the information about the input field like name and id and stuff, but not the content..... That is waht I am after...

Comment: @ployo60 - did you bother reading the first page, at least? It has a section titled 'Set the value of a named field'!

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera - Yes I have read the page and I don't expect the code from anyone, just a hint in the right direction. But the page does not describe what i am after. I dont want to set the value. I want to take the value when it is typed in. from webbrowser input field to an edit box on the form.....

Comment: @ployo60 - I insist - you need to read that documentation. What you want can be done if you modify the page and insert your own code. You can use some form of timer to get the values. I remember doing some pretty hairy stuff with the DOM back in my time. I know Nick Bradbury does some pretty nice things with it too in his FeedDemon program.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera - yeah I had a look at that as well. I'm going to have a closer look on the idea. But I do understand what you mean now! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('input-field-id').value
```

returns the contents of an input box. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to be able to return the information typed in a input field on a website in twebbrowser to an memobox or edit box.

Comment: TWebBrowser provides access to the DOM.

Comment: @TOndrej I didn't know that. How convenient is the access it provides?

Comment: Yeah? ok, are you able to copy the content of input field with it?

Comment: @ployo60 Try using websearch. It's exposed through: IWebBrowser2::Document (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752116%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes that's what I meant, you've found it yourself.

Comment: sorry I dont know how to use Iwebbrowser2.no idea in delphi

Comment: @ployo60 TWebBrowser is IWebBrowser2. They are one and the same. You just read the Document property. You'll have to learn how to do so and I suggest you do some reading and websearch.

Comment: ok, but you think I will be able to retrieve information typed in a input field this way and place it into a edit of memo this way?

Comment: @ployo60 do you know what a DOM is?

Comment: Document Object Model, yeah a bit but not very well. i dont think i know it well enough to understand what i want to do

Comment: @ployo60 time to do some research